# Append hash to iframe src with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, src

I need to append a hash `#play` to the `src` attribute on an iframe element once a link is clicked.

Here is what I have attempted so far:

```
$(".portfolio-link").click(function() {
  $('.first').append(.attr('src', '#play'));
});
```

Here is the link that I want to add `#play` to the `src` attribute on click: `<a href="#portfolioModal1" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal"></a>`

Here is the iframe element: `<iframe class="first" src="http://my.iframe.url" width="160" height="600" frameborder="0"></iframe>`

How can I accomplish this with jQuery?

Comment: $(".first').attr('src', $(".first").attr('src')+'#play' ) should do the trick...

Comment: @Snowmonkey Please add that as an answer.

Comment: Yes, please add as an answer. That worked.

Comment: glad to help. done and done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a couple of ways. first, you could save the src as a variable and use that:

```
var myUrl = $('.first').attr('src');
$('.first').attr('src', myUrl + "#play");
```

or you could do it all in a single step:

```
$('.first').attr('src', $('.first').attr('src')+"#play" );
```

Either should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
var currentSrc = $('iframe.first').attr('src');
$('iframe.first').attr('src', currentSrc + '#play');
```